# Dynamic JSON parsing and add search in Android

Tags: android, json, dynamic

[image]

How to parse this dynamic API products (bikes,cars) and inside Products[]? I need to bind in recyclerview vertical (bikes) and horizontal (Products).

Also I need to add search bar far these products.

I tried nested for loop using two arraylist but second Products data comes all the data together that means horizontal I was bind it from static arraylist. I don't know how to split it.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: i have created models, adapter and design then i parsed all the datas but in adapter all the datas in 2 arraylist values comes togther.(Products values ).

Comment: i have parsed all the first products in for loop then inside another for loop was created but i dont know how to handle 2 arraylist same time